# Tomcat is returning HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request status when I try to send special characters in URL

Tags: tomcat, urlencode, tomcat9, http-status-code-400

Whenever I try to put special characters in the URL as follows in the Mozilla Firefox browser

> https://URL/|

or

> https://URL/]

Tomcat is returning HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
and exception stack trace as follows.

```
Type Exception Report

Message Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:474)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Surprisingly same URL with special characters works properly in Google Chrome browser.

I have the following questions

1. What changes should I do in the tomcat configuration file so that it shouldn't return 400 status code and exception stack trace?
2. Why Mozilla Firefox is failing to encode the URL?

Note: I have already configured one common page for the status code of type 4XX in my application deployed at tomcat 9 but problem is tomcat is returning 400 bad request http status code in response at first place itself.

Comment: You tagged with [tag:urlencode] but obviously you aren't doing it. (Chrome does, as should any browser.) Have you considered encoding your URL properly? and *not* putting illegal characters into it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1 - allow the characters:

If you need to allow the characters, add the `relaxedQueryChars` and/or `relaxedPathChars` attributes to the `Connector` element in the server.xml file. Something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           relaxedQueryChars="[]{}^|"
           relaxedPathChars="[]{}^|"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

The documentation for those attributes is here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation

#### Option 2 - nice error page:

If you want to disallow those characters, but display a nice error page instead of a stack trace, add an Error Report Valve to the `Host` element in the server.xml. Something like:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       errorCode.400="webapps/ROOT/server_error.html"/>
```

The documentation for that Valve is here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable and not leak any of stack trace you can add this to server.xml

```
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
               showReport="false"
               showServerInfo="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

see relaxedPathChars and relaxedQueryChars from here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html you need to set them to all prior characters that were allowed without escaping

Comment: Include the relevant parts from the link in your answer please.