# Fix Tomcat 10 400 for multipart/form-data

Tags: jersey, multipartform-data, tomcat10

I am using Tomcat 10 and Jersey *3.1.0* (with *jersey-media-multipart*).

Then I have setup this resource:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFileForProfBuilding(final @Context SecurityContext sc,
    @FormParam(Files.FORM_DATA_KEY_DATA) String data,
    @FormParam(Files.FORM_DATA_KEY_FILE) EntityPart part) {

    this.logger.debug("uploading file: {},{},{},{}",

        part.getMediaType(), part.getName(), part.getFileName(), part.getHeaders());

    // ...
}
```

In my frontend I am calling this resource by doing

```
const formData     = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file); // which is a File
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(config.jsonData));

// ...
// roughly
return fetch('api/files/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : '' // actually some token
    },
    body: formData 
})
```

But Tomcat returns a 400 with `The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).`. The resource/endpoint is not reached at all.

I cannot see any Exception in my *Catalina.out*.

#### Tomcat interaction with *jersey-media-multipart*?

What else is needed to let Tomcat understand the parameters of the resource (`@FromParam` (Jakarta) or `@FormDataParam` (Jersey Multipart))?

#### Other hints

Parameter
`import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;` does not work, too.
Changing it to `@FormParam(Files.FORM_DATA_KEY_FILE) File file` also changes nothing.

The problem is very likely not related to the URL (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810433/tomcat-is-returning-http-status-400-bad-request-status-when-i-try-to-send-spec)), but to the `FromParam`, but I cannot see, how.

Do I need to specify the `PartType` for the single form parts [like this](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-multipart#setting-up-the-model):

```
public class MultipartBody {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public InputStream file;

    @FormParam("fileName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String fileName;
}
```

But I do not have an additional library for a usage of this class like this:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.providers.multipart.MultipartForm;

// then defining the resource:
Response sendMultipartData(@MultipartForm MultipartBody data);
```

Comment: 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' does not seem correct, for multipart you should have something like 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_1_511262261_1369143433608'. Jersey updates the Content-Type header during the entity processing, but the unusual client you use perhaps does not update the headers before writing the entity